# How to display two views using two different models on the same web page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is the code for controllers and view. I want to display the both views on the same webpage in ASP.NET MVC. How to achieve this goal?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult LetterList()
{
   LetterPage.Models.ModelView obj = new LetterPage.Models.ModelView();

   obj.letterDetail = new List<LetterList>()
        {
        new LetterList() { ListId = "1", ListName =  "A" },
        new LetterList() { ListId = "2",  ListName= "B" },
        new LetterList() { ListId = "3",  ListName= "C" },
        new LetterList() { ListId ="4",  ListName= "D"}
        };

    return View(obj);
}

public ActionResult Showimage(string ListId)
{
        Post post = new Post();
        var letterList = post.FindByletter_Id(ListId);

         return View(letterList);
}
```

View Of LetterList

```
     @model LetterPage.Models.ModelView

   <div>
   @{
    foreach (var item in Model.letterDetail)
    {
        <div>
            <a href="/Home/ShowImage?ListId=@item.ListId">@item.ListName</a>
        </div>
      }
     }
     </div>
```

ShowImage view:

```
    @model IList< LetterPage.Models.hurf_e_tahaji>

     @{
     ViewBag.Title = "ShowImage";
     }

   <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>
     </th>
     </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="@Url.Content("item.Letter_Pic") "/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    }

    </table>
```

When I created these views as partial views and render them into another view exception occurs on the `Foreach` loop at model.

Comment: You can use PartialViews

Comment: You can create a new model for this particular view that has two properties -- your letterlist model and your showimage model. Fill both models in your controller action.

Comment: An alternative to using a view model combining both properties is to simply use `@Html.Action("LetterList")` in your `Showimage.cshtml` view (which will include the partial view generated by the `LetterList()` method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for helping me out , it worked fine. i want to ask another question. when the first time page is loaded nothing is displayed except list of letters. how to set the the 1st list item selected by default so when the page is loaded its respected pictures are also displayed along with the list, without selecting any list item. please help.

Comment: Your going to have to ask a new question with a bit more detail including your code  (comments aren't for asking new questions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PartialView:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult LetterList()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            LetterPage.Models.ModelView obj = new    LetterPage.Models.ModelView();
            obj.letterDetail = new List<LetterList>()
            {
                new LetterList() { ListId = "1", ListName =  "A" },
                new LetterList() { ListId = "2",  ListName= "B" },
                new LetterList() { ListId = "3",  ListName= "C" },
                new LetterList() { ListId ="4",  ListName= "D"}
            };
            return PartialView(obj);
        }
        return null;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Showimage(string ListId)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            Post post = new Post();
            var letterList = post.FindByletter_Id(ListId);
            return PartialView(letterList);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then you have to define your partial views (like code you posted), And inside the main view:

```
<div class="LetterList">
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/arrow-spinner-blue.gif")" alt="loading" />
</div>
<div class="Showimage">
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/arrow-spinner-blue.gif")" alt="loading" />
</div>
@section Scripts
{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.post('/Home/LetterList', function(data) {
                $('.LetterList').html(data);
            });
            $.post('/Home/Showimage/' + ListId, function(data) {
                $('.Showimage').html(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```